# Can't update nested attributes / Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Models:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :house_type
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :house_type
end

class HouseType < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :house
end
```

My houses_controller

```
def update
    house = House.find(params[:id])
    if house.update!(house_type_params)
        render :json => trip
    end
end

private
def house_type_params
    params.permit(:attr1, :attr2, house_type_attributes: [:attrA, :attrB])
end
```

That way it only updates houses' attributes, not house_types'. Don't know what's happening. Help, please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471104/nested-attributes-for-belongs-to-association-rails

Comment: Note that `if house.update!` doesn't make sense because `update!` never returns false but instead raises an error if saving fails. Use `if house.update` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working :(